# Clustering with features of categorical type

Tags: clustering, categorical-data, beginner

I have a dataset of 17 features and class label for each datapoint. The description of dataset is as follows:

- 2 features contain values 0, 1, 2, 3
- 15 features contain values 0, 1, 2
- class label containing value 0 or 1

I am given a set of clustering algorithms namely KNN, DBSCAN, Agglomerative clustering, Self Organizing Maps(SOM) and asked to implement each of these algorithm for the above dataset. I implemented them and plotted the obtained clusters with respective any of the two features on a scatter plot. Then I realized that there is no use doing clustering because either all of the points are considered a single cluster or each datapoint is considered a separate cluster.

I also tried one-hot encoding and then perform clustering, still the same result

Is there any use applying clustering algorithms on such data or am I doing something wrong in the implementation part here

Any help is appreciated

Comment: first thing to check: take a well-known dataset (e.g. Iris) and apply your algorithm implementations on. Do you get good result?

Comment: @Ipounng Yes, I applied all the algorithms for Iris dataset and results were good, maybe because it was a continuous dataset. I am trying to understand the results obtained for the discrete value dataset.